# Can a switch case do something like this?

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

My idea is that I have buttons on my app that leads to a single activity. I want it to have the same text template but different contents appearing when different buttons are clicked. I already have the XML file done, I got stuck on the code. I was thinking of using switch case but can it be possibly done with switch case? Or am I being too ambitious?

EDIT: Here's the code I have so far:

```
public class SelectKeys extends Activity {


private static final int[] buttonIDs = {R.id.cKey, R.id.cSharpKey, R.id.dKey, R.id.dSharpKey, R.id.eKey, R.id.fKey, R.id.fSharpKey, R.id.gKey, R.id.gSharpKey, R.id.aKey, R.id.aSharpKey, R.id.bKey};

private Button[] bt = new Button[buttonIDs.length];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_keys);

    for (int i = 0; i < buttonIDs.length; i++) {
        final int b = i;
        bt[b] = (Button) findViewById(buttonIDs[i]); // Fetch the view id from array
        bt[b].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //opens up new screen
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChordKeys.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                }
            });


        }
    }

public final void keyButton(final View v)
{
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.cKey:
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_key_c);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.cSharpKey:
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_csharp_dflat);
            break;
        }
        // adding more cases later once I get this to work
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can have a centralized click listener (referred in your xml layout) and a switch-case (in Java) to execute the proper code bits depending on the View id.

Comment: I like how using a switch statement is now "ambitious".

Comment: Lol it's more to what I actually planned on doing, not the switch statement. I may have worded it wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it can be done with a switch case, you just need to create a class that implements `onClickListener`, and link all your buttons with this listener, like this:

```
    final Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new MyButtonListener());

    class MyButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener{

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int id=v.getId();
            switch (id){
                case R.id.button1:
                    button.setText("Text1");
                    break;
                case **:
                    break;

                default:
                    break;

            }
```

Comment: I used this code as my reference, tweaked it a little but my app crashed when I tested it. I forgot to mention I have array in my code.

Comment: this is just a simplified code but not a complete one...just to tell u a solution for your question..  you mind to post you code ?

Answer (score 0):

To have a centralized Click handler which can be addressed in your xml layout:

Add this method to your Java code

```
public final void clickHandler(final View v)
{
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btn1:
        {
            // Do something, when you click btn1
            break;
        }
        case R.id.btn2:
        {
            // Do something else, when you click btn2
            break;
        }
        // ... more cases ...
    }
}
```

In your xml layout:

```
    ...

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        ...
        android:onClick="clickHandler"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        ...
        android:onClick="clickHandler"
    />

    ...
```

---

Note (1): This is valid **not only** for Buttons, but also for ImageButtons, ImageViews, TextViews, ...

Note (2): You can use it with **mixed Views** at the same time (i.e.: a Button, 2 TextViews and an ImageView can all address the same `clikHandler()` method).

Comment: I get the idea now. But my problem now is trying to figure out where to place the code. I have two Java classes, one is SelectKeys and the other one is ChordKeys. SelectKeys has the codes for the buttons that leads to a different activity. I tried putting it in either one of them and for some reason, the layout doesn't appear on the screen. I could post the codes but idk how especially in the comments.

Comment: To post some code, simply **edit your question**. The `clickHandler()` method must be in the Java of the Activity which holds the buttons.

Comment: You should remove the onClick listener, since it conflicts with the clickHandler method.

Comment: Removing the onClick listener solves it and it shows the screens but when I clicked the button, the layout instantly pops up, unlike the transition thing when I had the startActivity(intent). Pressing the back button on my phone returns back to the main menu instead of the previous screen that has all the buttons.

Comment: Frankly, I don't get what are you trying to do. If you only change layout, but the Activity remains the same (main), you will get to the home screen on back press (no back stack). You probably want to swap Fragments in the same Activity (so, on Back Press you'll return to the previous Fragment).

Comment: My main menu is the MainActivity which leads to SelectKeys that contains the buttons. Pressing the buttons will lead to the XML layout, so if I press back, I want it to return to SelectKeys.

Comment: Yeah, my main menu has two buttons that lead to two different sections. I am branching stuff in this app lol. My biggest problem is the SelectKeys part. The others are still bearable. 

This "Please avoid extended discussions in comments" scares me. I am new to this place and I don't wanna get into trouble.

Comment: No trouble. Well. You should then swap 2 Fragments (the sub sections) each of which with its specific set of buttons in its specific layout (and with its specific clickHandler method). Swapping the contentView is not a great idea.

Comment: So, is switch statement still in the picture in this case? I am not entirely familiar with Fragments. Does this mean I have to build Fragments into the Activity?

Comment: You should read about Fragments - More or less they are interchangeable Activity parts with their own layout. And you can replace them at any time.

Comment: Hm I've read about Fragments and I found a tutorial that gives the fragment layout that I want but there are some codes that confuse me. The tutorial uses string data as the details, I want to link mine to the XML layouts I have, is there a way?

Comment: I don't have an idea of your tutorial, Anyway, the (obvious) answer is: Yes, there is.